# Integrate fails while NIntegrate works

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I'm having an odd issue where I am integrating a function (`f`) (a summation of Legendre polynomials so a polynomial of large order) on a finite domain where the function *should* be normalized to unity (1).  `NIntegrate[f,{x,-6,0}]` yields the desired result of 1. however `Integrate[f,{x,a,0}]` yields `-2.87958*10^6`.  Any idea on why this is behaving oddly?

Here is the specific function I am integrating from -6 to 0:

```
f = (-0.0884787 + 0.124558 (3 + x) + 0.0555223 (6 + 6 x + x^2) - 
   0.00351543 (54 + 108 x + 45 x^2 + 5 x^3) - 
   0.000150858 (648 + 2160 x + 1620 x^2 + 420 x^3 + 35 x^4) - 
   0.000203337 (216 + 1080 x + 1260 x^2 + 560 x^3 + 105 x^4 + 
      7 x^5) + 
   0.0000120346 (3888 + 27216 x + 45360 x^2 + 30240 x^3 + 9450 x^4 + 
      1386 x^5 + 77 x^6) + 
   3.29321*10^-6 (11664 + 108864 x + 244944 x^2 + 226800 x^3 + 
      103950 x^4 + 24948 x^5 + 3003 x^6 + 143 x^7) - 
   3.43085*10^-7 (93312 + 1119744 x + 3265920 x^2 + 3991680 x^3 + 
      2494800 x^4 + 864864 x^5 + 168168 x^6 + 17160 x^7 + 715 x^8) + 
   3.82638*10^-9 (2519424 + 37791360 x + 138568320 x^2 + 
      215550720 x^3 + 175134960 x^4 + 81729648 x^5 + 22702680 x^6 + 
      3706560 x^7 + 328185 x^8 + 12155 x^9) + 
   1.59919*10^-9 (15116544 + 277136640 x + 1247114880 x^2 + 
      2401850880 x^3 + 2451889440 x^4 + 1471133664 x^5 + 
      544864320 x^6 + 126023040 x^7 + 17721990 x^8 + 1385670 x^9 + 
      46189 x^10) - 
   1.0545*10^-9 (15116544 + 332563968 x + 1801388160 x^2 + 
      4203239040 x^3 + 5254048800 x^4 + 3923023104 x^5 + 
      1852538688 x^6 + 567103680 x^7 + 112239270 x^8 + 13856700 x^9 + 
      969969 x^10 + 29393 x^11) - 
   2.43415*10^-11 (544195584 + 14149085184 x + 90789963264 x^2 + 
      252194342400 x^3 + 378291513600 x^4 + 342984305664 x^5 + 
      200074178304 x^6 + 77579783424 x^7 + 20203068600 x^8 + 
      3491888400 x^9 + 384107724 x^10 + 24337404 x^11 + 
      676039 x^12) + 
   2.79113*10^-12 (1632586752 + 49521798144 x + 371413486080 x^2 + 
      1210532843520 x^3 + 2143651910400 x^4 + 2315144063232 x^5 + 
      1629175451904 x^6 + 775797834240 x^7 + 254558664360 x^8 + 
      57616158600 x^9 + 8834477652 x^10 + 876146544 x^11 + 
      50702925 x^12 + 1300075 x^13) + 
   4.18636*10^-12 (1088391168 + 38093690880 x + 330145320960 x^2 + 
      1247215656960 x^3 + 2572382292480 x^4 + 3258350903808 x^5 + 
      2715292419840 x^6 + 1551595668480 x^7 + 622254512880 x^8 + 
      176689553040 x^9 + 35337910608 x^10 + 4867480800 x^11 + 
      439425350 x^12 + 23401350 x^13 + 557175 x^14) - 
   4.94232*10^-13 (3265173504 + 130606940160 x + 1295185489920 x^2 + 
      5612470456320 x^3 + 13329617333760 x^4 + 19550105422848 x^5 + 
      19007046938880 x^6 + 12800664264960 x^7 + 6133651626960 x^8 + 
      2120274636480 x^9 + 530068659120 x^10 + 94915875600 x^11 + 
      11864484450 x^12 + 982856700 x^13 + 48474225 x^14 + 
      1077205 x^15) - 
   6.58242*10^-15 (156728328192 + 7105017544704 x + 
      79931447377920 x^2 + 393736388935680 x^3 + 
      1066369386700800 x^4 + 1791500569657344 x^5 + 
      2007144156745728 x^6 + 1570214816501760 x^7 + 
      883245834282240 x^8 + 363475651968000 x^9 + 
      110254281096960 x^10 + 24602194955520 x^11 + 
      3986466775200 x^12 + 456045508800 x^13 + 34901442000 x^14 + 
      1602881040 x^15 + 33393355 x^16) + 
   1.12912*10^-14 (156728328192 + 7993144737792 x + 
      101246500012032 x^2 + 562480555622400 x^3 + 
      1722596701593600 x^4 + 3284417711038464 x^5 + 
      4196755964104704 x^6 + 3768515559604224 x^7 + 
      2453460650784000 x^8 + 1181295868896000 x^9 + 
      425266512802560 x^10 + 114810243125760 x^11 + 
      23121507296160 x^12 + 3420341316000 x^13 + 360648234000 x^14 + 
      25646096640 x^15 + 1101980715 x^16 + 21607465 x^17) - 
   3.56274*10^-17 (8463329722368 + 482409794174976 x + 
      6834138750812160 x^2 + 42523530005053440 x^3 + 
      146174634392371200 x^4 + 313788215162290176 x^5 + 
      453249644123308032 x^6 + 462499636860518400 x^7 + 
      344465875370073600 x^8 + 191369930761152000 x^9 + 
      80375370919683840 x^10 + 25684691533562880 x^11 + 
      6242806969963200 x^12 + 1145130272596800 x^13 + 
      155800037088000 x^14 + 15233781404160 x^15 + 
      1011618296370 x^16 + 40838108850 x^17 + 756261275 x^18) - 
   8.75997*10^-18 (25389989167104 + 1608032647249920 x + 
      25326514194186240 x^2 + 175409561270845440 x^3 + 
      672403318204907520 x^4 + 1613767963691778048 x^5 + 
      2614901793019084800 x^6 + 3006247639593369600 x^7 + 
      2536521445906905600 x^8 + 1607507418393676800 x^9 + 
      776961918890277120 x^10 + 288952779752582400 x^11 + 
      82940149743796800 x^12 + 18322084361548800 x^13 + 
      3084840734342400 x^14 + 388461425806080 x^15 + 
      35406640372950 x^16 + 2205257877900 x^17 + 83945001525 x^18 + 
      1472719325 x^19) + 
   2.1851*10^-17 (101559956668416 + 7109196966789120 x + 
      123818513838243840 x^2 + 949275272759869440 x^3 + 
      4034419909229445120 x^4 + 10758453091278520320 x^5 + 
      19424984748141772800 x^6 + 24974980390467993600 x^7 + 
      23674200161797785600 x^8 + 16951896412151500800 x^9 + 
      9323543026683325440 x^10 + 3981127187702246400 x^11 + 
      1327042395900748800 x^12 + 345502162246348800 x^13 + 
      69923056645094400 x^14 + 10876919922570240 x^15 + 
      1274639053426200 x^16 + 108792721976400 x^17 + 
      6379820115900 x^18 + 229744214700 x^19 + 
      3829070245 x^20))^2 + (-0.0884787 - 0.124558 (3 + x) + 
   0.0555223 (6 + 6 x + x^2) + 
   0.00351543 (54 + 108 x + 45 x^2 + 5 x^3) - 
   0.000150858 (648 + 2160 x + 1620 x^2 + 420 x^3 + 35 x^4) + 
   0.000203337 (216 + 1080 x + 1260 x^2 + 560 x^3 + 105 x^4 + 
      7 x^5) + 
   0.0000120346 (3888 + 27216 x + 45360 x^2 + 30240 x^3 + 9450 x^4 + 
      1386 x^5 + 77 x^6) - 
   3.29321*10^-6 (11664 + 108864 x + 244944 x^2 + 226800 x^3 + 
      103950 x^4 + 24948 x^5 + 3003 x^6 + 143 x^7) - 
   3.43085*10^-7 (93312 + 1119744 x + 3265920 x^2 + 3991680 x^3 + 
      2494800 x^4 + 864864 x^5 + 168168 x^6 + 17160 x^7 + 715 x^8) - 
   3.82638*10^-9 (2519424 + 37791360 x + 138568320 x^2 + 
      215550720 x^3 + 175134960 x^4 + 81729648 x^5 + 22702680 x^6 + 
      3706560 x^7 + 328185 x^8 + 12155 x^9) + 
   1.59919*10^-9 (15116544 + 277136640 x + 1247114880 x^2 + 
      2401850880 x^3 + 2451889440 x^4 + 1471133664 x^5 + 
      544864320 x^6 + 126023040 x^7 + 17721990 x^8 + 1385670 x^9 + 
      46189 x^10) + 
   1.0545*10^-9 (15116544 + 332563968 x + 1801388160 x^2 + 
      4203239040 x^3 + 5254048800 x^4 + 3923023104 x^5 + 
      1852538688 x^6 + 567103680 x^7 + 112239270 x^8 + 13856700 x^9 + 
      969969 x^10 + 29393 x^11) - 
   2.43415*10^-11 (544195584 + 14149085184 x + 90789963264 x^2 + 
      252194342400 x^3 + 378291513600 x^4 + 342984305664 x^5 + 
      200074178304 x^6 + 77579783424 x^7 + 20203068600 x^8 + 
      3491888400 x^9 + 384107724 x^10 + 24337404 x^11 + 
      676039 x^12) - 
   2.79113*10^-12 (1632586752 + 49521798144 x + 371413486080 x^2 + 
      1210532843520 x^3 + 2143651910400 x^4 + 2315144063232 x^5 + 
      1629175451904 x^6 + 775797834240 x^7 + 254558664360 x^8 + 
      57616158600 x^9 + 8834477652 x^10 + 876146544 x^11 + 
      50702925 x^12 + 1300075 x^13) + 
   4.18636*10^-12 (1088391168 + 38093690880 x + 330145320960 x^2 + 
      1247215656960 x^3 + 2572382292480 x^4 + 3258350903808 x^5 + 
      2715292419840 x^6 + 1551595668480 x^7 + 622254512880 x^8 + 
      176689553040 x^9 + 35337910608 x^10 + 4867480800 x^11 + 
      439425350 x^12 + 23401350 x^13 + 557175 x^14) + 
   4.9423*10^-13 (3265173504 + 130606940160 x + 1295185489920 x^2 + 
      5612470456320 x^3 + 13329617333760 x^4 + 19550105422848 x^5 + 
      19007046938880 x^6 + 12800664264960 x^7 + 6133651626960 x^8 + 
      2120274636480 x^9 + 530068659120 x^10 + 94915875600 x^11 + 
      11864484450 x^12 + 982856700 x^13 + 48474225 x^14 + 
      1077205 x^15) - 
   6.58242*10^-15 (156728328192 + 7105017544704 x + 
      79931447377920 x^2 + 393736388935680 x^3 + 
      1066369386700800 x^4 + 1791500569657344 x^5 + 
      2007144156745728 x^6 + 1570214816501760 x^7 + 
      883245834282240 x^8 + 363475651968000 x^9 + 
      110254281096960 x^10 + 24602194955520 x^11 + 
      3986466775200 x^12 + 456045508800 x^13 + 34901442000 x^14 + 
      1602881040 x^15 + 33393355 x^16) - 
   1.12909*10^-14 (156728328192 + 7993144737792 x + 
      101246500012032 x^2 + 562480555622400 x^3 + 
      1722596701593600 x^4 + 3284417711038464 x^5 + 
      4196755964104704 x^6 + 3768515559604224 x^7 + 
      2453460650784000 x^8 + 1181295868896000 x^9 + 
      425266512802560 x^10 + 114810243125760 x^11 + 
      23121507296160 x^12 + 3420341316000 x^13 + 360648234000 x^14 + 
      25646096640 x^15 + 1101980715 x^16 + 21607465 x^17) - 
   3.56262*10^-17 (8463329722368 + 482409794174976 x + 
      6834138750812160 x^2 + 42523530005053440 x^3 + 
      146174634392371200 x^4 + 313788215162290176 x^5 + 
      453249644123308032 x^6 + 462499636860518400 x^7 + 
      344465875370073600 x^8 + 191369930761152000 x^9 + 
      80375370919683840 x^10 + 25684691533562880 x^11 + 
      6242806969963200 x^12 + 1145130272596800 x^13 + 
      155800037088000 x^14 + 15233781404160 x^15 + 
      1011618296370 x^16 + 40838108850 x^17 + 756261275 x^18) + 
   9.22352*10^-18 (25389989167104 + 1608032647249920 x + 
      25326514194186240 x^2 + 175409561270845440 x^3 + 
      672403318204907520 x^4 + 1613767963691778048 x^5 + 
      2614901793019084800 x^6 + 3006247639593369600 x^7 + 
      2536521445906905600 x^8 + 1607507418393676800 x^9 + 
      776961918890277120 x^10 + 288952779752582400 x^11 + 
      82940149743796800 x^12 + 18322084361548800 x^13 + 
      3084840734342400 x^14 + 388461425806080 x^15 + 
      35406640372950 x^16 + 2205257877900 x^17 + 83945001525 x^18 + 
      1472719325 x^19) + 
   2.20904*10^-17 (101559956668416 + 7109196966789120 x + 
      123818513838243840 x^2 + 949275272759869440 x^3 + 
      4034419909229445120 x^4 + 10758453091278520320 x^5 + 
      19424984748141772800 x^6 + 24974980390467993600 x^7 + 
      23674200161797785600 x^8 + 16951896412151500800 x^9 + 
      9323543026683325440 x^10 + 3981127187702246400 x^11 + 
      1327042395900748800 x^12 + 345502162246348800 x^13 + 
      69923056645094400 x^14 + 10876919922570240 x^15 + 
      1274639053426200 x^16 + 108792721976400 x^17 + 
      6379820115900 x^18 + 229744214700 x^19 + 3829070245 x^20))^2
```

Comment: Hi; It would help if you posted your mathematica code.

Comment: You are probably being bitten by having very large integer coefficients, floating point constants with only 6 digits and large powers of x in your polynomial. If I try to translate your Latex back to Mathematica and append 20 zeros to the end of each of your decimal values then Integrate gives 0.6. But it is possible that I've made one or more mistakes translating the Latex. NIntegrate and Integrate will take very different paths to their results and that likely explains why you are getting different results.

Comment: @Bill Might be that this is because exponents > 9 seem to be messed up in his Latex code.

Comment: Bill is talking about something else entirely. Mixing single precision numbers and large integers as multipliers is going to promote smearing. First thing I would do is enter those floating point numbers as fractions. Fixing your latex is easy, when you have something like x^10 you must write it as x^{10}

Comment: You mention that horrific polynomial is the sum of Legendre polynomials. Which ones? If you post that it will be easier to integrate.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: It looks like you are working with the shifted Legendre polynomials. You shifted the Legendre polynomials from {-1,1} -> {-6,0}. But when I normalize I do not get those coefficients. Perhaps you should post a smaller example where you show all your work. Then maybe the mistake can be sorted out.

Comment: Hi everyone thank you for the replies and format corrections!  What solved the solution was increasing `Integrate[SetPrecision[f(x),Infinite],{x,0,6}]`.

bobbym I didn't post the full code because it is much more involved than this example! Also the summation is the result of the expansion of a function in Legendre polynomials, so I wouldn't expect the same coefficients for simply the normalized Legendre polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate [Bill's point](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130683/integrate-fails-while-nintregrate-works#comment352759_130683) that rounding error is above `10^6` in this case:

```
Integrate[f, {x, -6, 0}]
(*  -397528.`  *)

N@Integrate[SetPrecision[f, Infinity], {x, -6, 0}]
(*  0.9999974730132678`  *)
```

It's off because you probably posted the output form of the approximate coefficients, which are rounded to 6-digit precision.

Another look, by evaluating the antiderivative (not necessarily the same route `Integrate` takes with a definite integral). The error is a bit above the order of the error between `NIntegrate` and `Integrate` above.

```
a = Integrate[f, x];
res1 = a /. x -> -6
a = Integrate[SetPrecision[f, Infinity], x];
res2 = a /. x -> -6 // N
(*
  3.86662*10^6
  -0.9999974730132678` 
*)
```

It's also possible to store just the coefficients of a Legendre series and integrate via the rule

```
Clear[n, x];
Integrate[LegendreP[n, x], x]
(*  (-LegendreP[-1 + n, x] + LegendreP[1 + n, x])/(1 + 2 n)  *)
```

The internal evaluation algorithm is much more precise than evaluating the expanded polynomial:

```
LegendreP[20, x] /. x -> -1.`30 // Precision
LegendreP[20, -1.`30] // Precision
(*
  22.1277
  30.
*)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Bill and @Lukas are right. The precision of your floating point constants is not enough. If you Rationalize to maximum precision of your constants, you get the same results. See.

```
Rationalize[0.0884787, 0]
(* 884787/10000000   (*as an example *) *)

fR = Rationalize[f, 0];
nint = NIntegrate[fR, {x, -6, 0}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]    
(* 0.99999747301326789541639933226859032749589364770686 *)

int = Integrate[fR, {x, -6, 0}];
N[int, 50]
(* 0.99999747301326789541639933226859032749589364770686 *)
```